# How to use the standard login dialog instead of the GitHub Login dialog in TortoiseGit?

Tags: github, tortoise-git

I have some GitHub repositories. When I want to push some commits to the server I have to authenticate myself by using username and password (I don't want to change to another authentication method like ssh keys).

Unfortunately, every time I do a push I see the `GitHub Login` dialog.

[image: GitHUb Login]

I don't want to use it because it creates tokens in GitHub. After I clicked `Cancel` I finally see the standard dialog:

[image]

How could I permanently disable the `GitHub Login` dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have enabled the Windows Credential Manager (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) - that is normally done on Git for Windows installation.

You can disable switch to another credential manager globally or just for a specific repository (e.g., wincred, cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-credential).

Comment: I've configured to use `wincred` and `GitHub Login` does not appear anymore :)